# Break statement in Twig

Tags: php, twig, smarty

How we can use break statement in twig template?

Here is my php code

```
<?php 
     $i=0;
     foreach($products as $product){
       echo $product['name'];
       $i++;
       if($i==5){
         break;
       }
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You either limit the array size inside you controller, which is the *best* method, or you could use the filter `slice`

```
{% for product in products|slice(0,5) %}
   {{ product.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Twig` doesn't include a break statement. According to the official manual, the equivalent instruction is the `for + if condition`. Check the documentation [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition) for some alternative.

or

[here](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/654)